# Styled components interpolation

Tags: javascript, styled-components

I am wondering why everybody use styled components like this

```
export const Title = styled.div`
  margin-top: 48px;
  font-family: ${({ theme }) => theme.font};
  font-size: ${({ theme }) => theme.sizeBig};
  color: ${({ theme }) => theme.dark};
  font-weight: ${({ theme }) => theme.fontWeight}
`
```

Rather than something like

```
export const Title = styled.div`
  margin-top: 48px;
  ${({ theme }) => css`
    font-family: ${theme.font};
    font-size: ${theme.sizeBig};
    color: ${theme.dark};
    font-weight: ${theme.fontWeight}
  `}
`
```

Is there any reason to create arrow function on every line?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Comes down to personal preference. I actually go a little bit further in my apps:

```
export const Title = styled.div(({ theme }) => css`
  margin-top: 48px;
  font-family: ${theme.font};
  font-size: ${theme.sizeBig};
  color: ${theme.dark};
  font-weight: ${theme.fontWeight}
`)
```

I like it this way since each style is defined in a single template literal.

Styled Components marks some components as static as an optimisation step, if there's nothing to interpolate. Reading [this](https://medium.com/styled-components/how-styled-components-works-618a69970421), it seems like this approach would have no performance impact, since having just one property being interpolated marks the whole styled component as not static.